# Property with redefined accessor still accessible

Tags: objective-c

I am wondering the usefulness of redefining a getter of a property. 
The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) states that we can redefine the getter of a property by using `getter`:

```
@property (getter=isFinished) BOOL finished;
```

From what I understand, callers should then use:

```
MyObj *obj = ...;
obj.isFinished;
```

But nothing prevents you to do:

```
MyObj *obj = ...;
obj.finished;
```

Since the property itself can still be freely accessed, what's the point of redefining a getter?

Wouldn't it be more concise and readable to do:

```
@property BOOL isFinished;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `@property (getter=isFinished) BOOL finished;` you declare an explicit getter, an implicit setter, **and** an implicit ivar. (In former versions of ObjC, you have needed a `@synthesize in addition). 
However, there is no need that a getter/setter use the automatic ivar, not even an ivar at all. Thus, you can have an private ivar, or set an number of ivars, or do any other 'magic'.

The dot syntax is only syntactic sugar for avoid [].

**EDIT**
Till here, I answered your question "what's the point of redefining a getter?".

To answer the name/privacy part:
If you simply want a `BOOL`, your first alternative is fine. If you want a protected/private ivar, declare the ivar in that way, and write your own getter/setter.

To name the property `isFinished` is usually considered not so good (unless it is a read only property), since the original setting (not dot semantic) would look `setIsFinished:val` (instead of `setFinished:val`), what is considered as not so easy readable. However, to have a getter `isFinished` allows for `if ([obj isFinished]) ...`  or `if (obj.isFinished) ...` that is usually considered quite well readable.

Thus, naming and privacy are independent concepts.

Comment: I don't want to use any number of ivars or anything. Just a plain `BOOL`. What's the best practice then ?

Comment: Thanks for the precisions

Answer (score 1):

The declared property is named "finished". The getter method is `isFinished`, but this doesn't make `obj.isFinished` the correct dot syntax for it. Dot syntax should use the name of the property, not the getter. It's more or less an accident that `obj.isFinished` compiles. It's not a reference to the declared "finished" property. The compiler effectively searches for an implicit property and one thing which implicitly defines a property is the existence of a method which takes no arguments and returns a value. Hence, you have an explicit "finished" property and an implicit "isFinished" property.

For example, you can abuse dot syntax to invoke `-[NSTask suspend]` via `someTask.suspend`. "suspend" isn't really the name of a property or even a getter, but the compiler can't tell the difference between a getter and a method which takes no arguments and returns a value, so it lets you get away with it. It's a bad idea, of course.

Your `obj.isFinished` isn't an abuse like that, of course, since you're invoking an actual getter. It's just that the compiler isn't referencing the declared property when it figures out what you're doing, it's just noticing the existence of a method of the right form.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation

Answer (score -1):

because by the naming convention you will get better idea of the property.It is required for your needs.