# Is property getter called even if I access property by name?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Let's say that I declare property in following way:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, getter = isWorking) BOOL working;
```

Then instead of having the property to be synthesized I write the getter myself (and add some custom logic to it).

What will happen if I access the property in following way:

```
BOOL work = self.working;
```

Is the getter (and my custom logic there) still called or is it called only when I access the property using getter explicitly (`BOOL work = self.isWorking;`) ?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220028/dot-syntax-vs-method-syntax-with-getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oops.**  Just tried it.  Apparently i use dot notation too much, and didn't realize just how much it was doing.  :P

```
#import "NSObject.h"
#include <stdio.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
@property (getter=myStuff) int stuff;
@end

@implementation Test
-(int)myStuff { return 42; }
-(void)setStuff:(int)value { /* don't care */ }
@end


int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Test* test = [[Test alloc] init];

        /* All these work... */
        printf("test.stuff == %d\n", test.stuff);
        printf("[test myStuff] == %d\n", [test myStuff]);
        printf("test.myStuff == %d\n", test.myStuff);

        /* but here, there's an exception */
        printf("[test stuff] == %d\n", [test stuff]);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

When i compile this (using clang in Linux), there are two warnings about the oddness of a missing `-(int)stuff`.  And the output looks like

```
chao@chao-VirtualBox:~/code/objc$ ./a.out
test.stuff == 42
[test myStuff] == 42
test.myStuff == 42
: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[Test stuff]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2367f38
chao@chao-VirtualBox:~/code/objc$
```

So, umm, yeah.  Disregard half of the stuff below.  :P

---

`self.working` is just syntactic sugar for <s>`[self working]` (or `[self setWorking:value]` if you're assigning to it).  Either one will do the same thing: return the value of</s> `[self isWorking]`, because that's the getter you defined.

If you want to avoid the getter, try `_working` or `self->_working` (or whatever you named the ivar).  Otherwise, `self.working`, <s>`[self working]`,</s> and `[self isWorking]`  (and even `self.isWorking` if you're feeling brave) should all give you the same result.

Comment: I do not want to avoid it - I want it to be always called. I know that `self.working` is just syntactic sugar for `[self working]` but my getter is not named `working` but `isWorking`. Please read my question carefully once again.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: please don't downvote helpful answers such as this one. It's quite correct, and directly responsive to the question.

Comment: In another words my question is whether `[self working]` calls my custom getter method named `isWorking` or if it access the ivar (`_working`) without calling the getter (is my custom logic granted to execute?).

Comment: @drasto: If `[self working]` does what it's supposed to, then `self.working` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: :( As I said before: *I do understand that `[self working]` and `self.working` it is the very same thing.* That is not the question. The question is whether `[self working]` and `[self isWorking]` is the same or not. Please, be so kind and read my original question and my comments in order to understand my question and the potential problem I am trying to avoid. Thank you.

Comment: @jlehr I downvoted it. The answer is "yes" which would be useful but the reasoning behind that "yes" suggests that the question was misinterpreted (or rather not read properly). Therefore the answer is more misleading then helpful. The correct answer to my question might still be "yes" (I hope so) but it seems to me that cHao's answered other question (not the one I asked). Please see my other comments for details.

Comment: Umm...of course it's the same thing.  You've explicitly arranged that `working`'s getter is `isWorking`.  So that's what'll be called when you try to get the property. I misinterpreted it because that seemed a given.  :P

Comment: Now it is great answer! My vote is +1 now. I prefer to ask before I take something as given...

Comment: This is slightly misleading; that's probably why it was downvoted, @jlehr. `self.propertyName;` is syntactic sugar for `[self propertyGetterName];`, whatever the getter name is. If the getter doesn't have the same name as the property, then saying the sugar is for `[self propertyName];` isn't correct. In fact, the method `- (propertytype) propertyName;` isn't created in that case, and you wouldn't be able to call it; the last sentence is completely wrong in that respect.

Comment: Josh Caswell is correct. There is no `-working` getter method here. `[self working]` won't work. It won't even compile. There is a property named "working", so that `self.working` compiles, but the getter is `-isWorking` and that's what it calls. See [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204945/property-with-redefined-accessor-still-accessible/18223804#18223804) to see why `self.isWorking` also works but is sort of wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, I should've read the question more carefully. Glad to see @cHao has updated his answer to clarify.

Comment: @KenThomases:  Oh...damn...yeah, you're right.  I thought for sure that ObjC was doing some stuff to respond to both messages, cause i'd semi-accidentally used `self.methodName` rather than `[self methodName]` and everything worked.  Turns out that dot means more than i thought it did.  :P  Edited with the results of my experiment.