# What does Objective-C property get resolved to in runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

What does Objective-C property get resolved to in runtime?  Will calling [obj valueForKey:@"property"] always yield the same result?

e.g.

obj.property

Comment: I am pretty sure somewhere in apple documentation described how `valueForKey` works in different platforms.

Comment: Can someone counter the down vote, this is a legit coding question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `obj.property` is precisely the same as `[obj property]`. Dot syntax is just syntactic sugar. While there are some small run-time implementation details related to properties that are different than other methods, for the purposes of this discussion, think only in terms of "I have an ivar named `_key` and a method called `-key`." The fact that you created that ivar and method by declaring a property is irrelevant for `valueForKey:`.

`valueForKey:` is a method, and it can be overridden by a class to return whatever it likes. The *default* behavior is that `valueForKey:` will first look for a method whose name matches the key, and will return the result of that. In the vast majority of cases, this means that if you have a property, then `valueForKey:@"property"` will return the value of it.

The full search path for the default implementation of `valueForKey:` is explained in ["Accessor Search Implementation Details"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA), but here is the "short" version:

- `get<Key>`, `<key>`, `is<Key>` (yes, the first place it looks is `getKey`, which is a little embarrassing because you should not prefix getters with `get` unless they return values by reference, but there you go; it is the first thing checked.)
- `countOf<Key>`, `objectIn<Key>AtIndex:`, and `<key>AtIndexes`. If a legal combination of these are found, then an NSArray-like proxy object is returned.
- `countOf<Key>`, `enumeratorOf<Key>`, and `memberOf<Key>:`. If all three are found, then an NSSet-like proxy object is returned.
- If `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` is `YES` (the default), then ivars are checked, named `_<key>`, `_is<Key>`, `<key>`, or `is<Key>`. Yes, this is a way to access an object's private ivars.
- If everything else failed, then it calls `valueForUndefinedKey:`, which is free to return a result (and this is in fact a very useful thing to do if you want a generic key/value store).

But nine times out of ten, you're going to get the value of the method named `<key>`.

Side note: `valueForKey:` returns an object. If the return is a number-like scalar (including `BOOL`), it will return an `NSNumber`. Otherwise it will return an `NSValue`. There is some special handling for `NSPoint`, `NSRange`, `NSRect`, and `NSSize` (on Mac; on iOS, only `NSRange` is handled specially I believe).

Comment: What about obj.property = value? Is that equivalent to [obj setProperty:value]?

Comment: Yes. dot-notation setters are converted to the relevant set method.

Comment: `obj.property` is [not quite the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18291735/319403) as `[obj property]`.  If the getter has a different name, the dot notation is equivalent to the sending of a message corresponding to the getter name, not the property name.

Comment: @cHao, good point. The conversion is from "dot notation to getter" and the default name for the getter is the name of the property. Similar for setter.

Answer (score 0):

obj.property is the same as [obj property], not [obj valueForKey:@"property"];. The latter is part of a system called Key Value Coding that's separate from properties.

Comment: It resolves to objc_msgSend, as all method calls do. Property accesses are just method calls.

Comment: class_getProperty does introspection. it isn't used to call anything