# What is objc_msgSend and why does it take up so much processing time?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been time profiling my turn based game app and I have run into an interesting (maybe) issue. As per the image below, it seems `objc_msgSend` takes up almost a minute of my app's run time. What is this and is it a sign of some poorly written code? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objc_msgSend` is the function which converts a selector into an address and jumps to it whenever you call a method in Objective-C. It's not an indication of poor programming in and of itself. But if it's taking the majority of your program's time, you may want to consider refactoring your code so that you don't need to call so many methods to do the work you're doing. Without any more information about your app it's impossible to tell you how to proceed.

I have hit this before. In my case, there was a method my app was calling to retrieve an `NSDictionary`. But it turned out that the dictionary was static throughout the app's lifetime. The method was creating it from scratch every time I called it. So instead of repeatedly calling the method that created the dictionary, I called it once at the beginning and saved (retained) the result eliminating all future calls to the method.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, what are examples that would lead to `objc_msgSend`. I understand your example, but would things like property access from different classes also invoke it? Examples:

`self.gameModel!.gameMapModel![Int(self.currentTileToOperateOn!.y)][Int(self.currentTileToOperateOn!.x)].tileType = .counter`

and:

`(self.mainBoardMap!.scene as! GameScene).gameCameraAndUI!.displayGameNotification(text: "Insufficient Counters", textColor: nil, completion: {})`

Comment: I believe that properties are implemented in a similar manner, though I'm not positive. You can read about the Objective-C runtime [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime?language=objc).

Comment: @Aleksandr I updated my answer with a bit more information about the runtime.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529694/what-does-objective-c-property-get-resolved-to-in-runtime) for some details.

Comment: @Aleksandr Sorry, I didn't notice your other question in the comment right away. Property accesses also go through `objc_msgSend`; they're basically a syntactic sugar that was introduced in Objective-C 2.0. In the old 1.0 days, we just accessed properties via the regular message-send notation—i.e. `[self someProperty]` and `[self setSomeProperty:newValue]` instead of `self.someProperty` and `self.someProperty = newValue`. The two notations still do the same thing under the hood.

Comment: Brilliant, big thanks in filling in the knowledge gap!

Answer (score 8):

As @user1118321 said above, `objc_msgSend` is basically the implementation of Objective-C's message dispatch. Basically, when you send a message such as `[foo bar]`, `objc_msgSend` gets invoked, and it essentially does this:

1. Figure out what class `foo` is.
2. Send the `bar` message (converted to a string-based selector) to `foo`, and get an implementation (which is basically a C function that takes `foo` and the selector as its first two arguments). This can be intercepted at runtime and manipulated in lots of gnarly ways, which is very cool but also incurs a performance cost. Also, the selector manipulation involves string operations, which incur a performance cost of their own.
3. Call the implementation from step 2.

If you want to get into the nitty-gritty of the inner workings of `objc_msgSend`, this article's pretty great: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-16-lets-build-objc_msgsend.html

Anyway, all this is obviously not going to be as fast as a straight C function call, but for the majority of cases, the overhead from `objc_msgSend` isn't enough to be a major concern (the function itself is written in some pretty hard-core hand-optimized assembler and uses a bunch of caching techniques, so it's probably pretty close to the optimal performance that it could have given all that it does). There are, however, some cases where `objc_msgSend`'s performance could be a concern, and for those cases you can try to minimize your use of Objective-C calls, as @user1118321 said. Alternatively, if you can narrow down the specific Objective-C method calls that are causing the problem, you can use a technique known as IMP caching, by which you can look up a method once and save its implementation as a C function pointer, which you can then call as repeatedly as you like, sending the object and selector as the first two arguments.

For example, if you have this object:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject

- (id)doSomethingWithString:(NSString *)bar;

@end
```

You can get its `IMP` like so:

```
Foo *foo = ...
SEL selector = @selector(doSomethingWithString:);
IMP imp = [foo methodForSelector:selector];
id (*funcVersion)(Foo *, SEL, NSString *) = (id (*)(Foo *, SEL, NSString *))imp;
```

You can store `funcVersion` and the selector somewhere, and then call it like this. You won't incur the cost of `objc_msgSend` in doing so, since you'll effectively be skipping the first two steps from the above list.

```
id returnValue = funcVersion(foo, selector, @"Baz");
```